# the difference between .bin file and .mat files

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow

can the tensorflow read a file contain a normal images for example in JPG, .... or the tensorflow just read the .bin file contains images

what is the difference between .mat file and .bin file

Also when I rename the .bin file name to .mat, does the data of the file changed??

sorry maybe my language not clear because I cannot speak English very well

Answer (score 0):

A '.mat' file contains [Matlab formatted Data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-file-formats.html) (not matlab code like you would expect from a '.m' file). I'm not sure if you're even using Matlab since you didn't include the the tag in your question. '.mat' files are associated with matlab workspace; if you wanted to save your current workspace in Matlab, you would save it as a '.mat' file.

A '.bin' file is a binary file read by the computer. In general, executable (ready-to-run) programs are often identified as binary files. I think this is what you would want to use. I am unsure what you really want though because the wording of the question is difficult to understand and it seems like you have two questions here.

Changing the suffix of a file just changes what will run the file. For example, if I were to change test.txt to test.py, the data inside the text file remains the same, but the way the file is opened has changed. In this case, the file was a text file usually opened using Notepad (or some variation) then it was opened by python once changed. If you were to change a .jpg file to a txt file, you wouldn't be able to view it as a picture again, but instead, you would open a text file with a bunch of seemingly random characters which describe the picture. The picture data never changed, but the way you see it and are able to use it does.

Take a look at [this](http://file.org/extension/bin) website which describes the .bin extension pretty well. Also, a quick Google search goes a long way especially with questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

A file-name suffix is just a suffix (which sometimes help to get info about that file; e.g. Windows decides which tool is called when double-clicked). A suffix does not need to be correct. And of course, changing the suffix will not change the content.

Every format will need their own decoder. JPG, PNG, MAT and co.

To some extent, these are automatically used by reading out metadata (giving some assumptions!). Many image-tools have some imread-function which works for jpg and png, even if there is no suffix (because there is checking for common and supported image-formats).

I'm not sure what tensorflow does automatically, but:

- jpg, png, bmp should be no problem

  - worst-case: use scipy to read and convert
- mat is usually a matrix (with infinite different encodings) and often matlab-based

  - scipy can read many matlab-based formats
- bin can be anything (usually stands for binary; no clear mapping like the above)

Don't get me wrong, but i expect someone trying to use tensorflow (not a small, not a simple tool) to know that changing a suffix should never magically transform the content to the new format (especially in the lossless/lossy case like png, jpg). I hope you evaluated this decision and you are not running blindly into using a popular tool.